# Possibly not calling function correctly

Tags: php, html, raspbian

I posted an issue earlier, and this most likely has something to do with it.

I try to fwrite() to a file right next to index.html, but it isn't working. I have set so everyone has all permissions.

Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['button1'])){test();}
function test()
{
    $f = fopen("test.txt", "w+");

fwrite($f, "Hello World");

fclose($f);
}
?>

<html><body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<input type=button onClick='location.href="?button1"' value='Toggle Lamp'>
</body></html>
```

Is it not calling the test() function properly?

EDIT: Whoops, that's not the entire code. Updated, sorry!

EDIT2: Doesn't work by calling just test(); either. Seems as if something is wrong in that function.

EDIT3: FIXED! Updated code to fixed code so others can see.

Comment: But where are you calling `test()` ?

Comment: Where do you call `test()`?

Comment: I don't see it calling `test()` anywhere, as a matter of fact.

Comment: Copypaste error, fixed!

Comment: Try this `if(isset($_GET['button1'])) {test();}`

Comment: `if($_GET['button1']){test();}` is testing `$_GET['button1']` for a truthy value, and only executing `test()` if it is truthy; but your request is passing an empty value, which is a non-truthy value.... change `<input type=button onClick='location.href="?button1"' value='Toggle Lamp'>` to `<input type=button onClick='location.href="?button1=1"' value='Toggle Lamp'>` to call with a truthy value

Comment: @Rupam: That didn't work.

Comment: It work by just calling the function ? Without the button click ?

Comment: @Mark Baker: That didn't work either. Maybe I'm using fwrite() incorrectly?

Comment: @Superdrac #DuhFace, why did I not try that? It doesn't work with just `test` either. Looks like something is wrong with my function.

Comment: This is where setting error display would be very useful

Comment: @user3433131 did you check the php logs ?

Comment: @MarkBaker What do you mean? Sorry for asking, I'm really new to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try `if(isset($_GET['button1'])) { test(); }`

As it stands, I believe you are implicitly asking it to see if `$_GET['button1'] == true` which is not what you have set in your `<a href="...">` tag in your HTML.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the corrections you made in your question's code.

Comment: This is actually what's going on, even if button1 is in get, it'll be empty so `if ($_GET['button1'])` evaluates to false. You could fix the href or change it to `if (isset($_GET['button1']))`

Answer (score 0):

Your fopen call is likely incorrect. You should give it the complete path to the file to write. If you're on apache you should be able to get the webroot path from $_SERVER['document_root'] or another environment variable. Or, if its really in the same directory as `index.php` use `__DIR__` constant:

```
$f = fopen(__DIR__ . "/test.txt", "w+");
```